External hard drive enclosure – disks do not show up on RPi CM4 (even though it works on MBP)
I have a Yottamaster Y-Focus Series-5 Bay FS5C3 SATA to USB-C hard drive storage enclosure with five HDDs in it.
When I connect it via USB-C to my MacBook Pro all the drives show up as expected.
But when I connect it to my Raspberry Pi CM4, none of the drives show up.
The harddrive enclosure uses external power, so I don't think it's a power issue.
I run Raspberry Pi OS.
OS version
cat /etc/issue

Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l

Kernel version
uname -a

Linux blixen 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

dmesg output after connecting harddrive enclosure
sudo dmesg -c

[  672.600991] usb 1-2.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  672.704661] usb 1-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2822, bcdDevice= 6.b3
[  672.704692] usb 1-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  672.704706] usb 1-2.1: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[  672.704718] usb 1-2.1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  672.704729] usb 1-2.1: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  672.713038] hub 1-2.1:1.0: USB hub found
[  672.713190] hub 1-2.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  672.784603] usb 2-2.1: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  672.876317] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0822, bcdDevice= 6.b3
[  672.876350] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  672.876364] usb 2-2.1: Product: USB3.1 Hub             
[  672.876376] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  672.876388] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  672.885817] hub 2-2.1:1.0: USB hub found
[  672.886572] hub 2-2.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  673.456979] usb 1-2.1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  673.607920] usb 1-2.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2822, bcdDevice= 6.73
[  673.607950] usb 1-2.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  673.607967] usb 1-2.1.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[  673.607981] usb 1-2.1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  673.607994] usb 1-2.1.3: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  673.616740] hub 1-2.1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[  673.617127] hub 1-2.1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  673.689654] usb 2-2.1.2: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  673.719335] usb 2-2.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0715, bcdDevice= 7.31
[  673.719358] usb 2-2.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  673.719372] usb 2-2.1.2: Product: VLI Product String
[  673.719384] usb 2-2.1.2: Manufacturer: VLI Manufacture String
[  673.719395] usb 2-2.1.2: SerialNumber: 000000123AE8
[  673.776729] scsi host0: uas
[  673.861815] usb 2-2.1.3: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  673.912822] usb 2-2.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0822, bcdDevice= 6.73
[  673.912841] usb 2-2.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  673.912851] usb 2-2.1.3: Product: USB3.1 Hub             
[  673.912860] usb 2-2.1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  673.912868] usb 2-2.1.3: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  673.921859] hub 2-2.1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[  673.922573] hub 2-2.1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  674.597650] usb 2-2.1.3.1: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  674.627079] usb 2-2.1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0715, bcdDevice= 7.31
[  674.627093] usb 2-2.1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  674.627100] usb 2-2.1.3.1: Product: VLI Product String
[  674.627106] usb 2-2.1.3.1: Manufacturer: VLI Manufacture String
[  674.627111] usb 2-2.1.3.1: SerialNumber: 000000123AE8
[  674.679185] scsi host1: uas
[  674.761655] usb 2-2.1.3.2: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  674.791084] usb 2-2.1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0715, bcdDevice= 7.31
[  674.791095] usb 2-2.1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  674.791102] usb 2-2.1.3.2: Product: VLI Product String
[  674.791108] usb 2-2.1.3.2: Manufacturer: VLI Manufacture String
[  674.791113] usb 2-2.1.3.2: SerialNumber: 000000123AE8
[  674.845526] scsi host2: uas
[  674.929662] usb 2-2.1.3.3: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  674.959074] usb 2-2.1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0715, bcdDevice= 7.31
[  674.959087] usb 2-2.1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  674.959094] usb 2-2.1.3.3: Product: VLI Product String
[  674.959100] usb 2-2.1.3.3: Manufacturer: VLI Manufacture String
[  674.959106] usb 2-2.1.3.3: SerialNumber: 000000123AE8
[  675.016944] scsi host3: uas
[  675.097676] usb 2-2.1.3.4: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  675.127080] usb 2-2.1.3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0715, bcdDevice= 7.31
[  675.127116] usb 2-2.1.3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  675.127124] usb 2-2.1.3.4: Product: VLI Product String
[  675.127129] usb 2-2.1.3.4: Manufacturer: VLI Manufacture String
[  675.127135] usb 2-2.1.3.4: SerialNumber: 000000123AE8
[  675.188401] scsi host4: uas
[  694.533332] scsi 0:0:0:0: tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  694.533365] scsi 0:0:0:0: tag#2 CDB: opcode=0x12 12 00 00 00 24 00
[  694.549354] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  694.641791] usb 2-2.1.2: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  694.688309] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  695.301342] scsi 1:0:0:0: tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  695.301371] scsi 1:0:0:0: tag#1 CDB: opcode=0x12 12 00 00 00 24 00
[  695.317359] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  695.409855] usb 2-2.1.3.1: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  695.456487] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  695.557350] scsi 2:0:0:0: tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  695.557372] scsi 3:0:0:0: tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  695.557375] scsi 2:0:0:0: tag#5 CDB: opcode=0x12 12 00 00 00 24 00
[  695.557391] scsi 3:0:0:0: tag#5 CDB: opcode=0x12 12 00 00 00 24 00
[  695.573364] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  695.573364] scsi host3: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  695.665936] usb 2-2.1.3.3: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  695.712544] scsi host3: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  695.773815] usb 2-2.1.3.2: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  695.817340] scsi 4:0:0:0: tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  695.817365] scsi 4:0:0:0: tag#2 CDB: opcode=0x12 12 00 00 00 24 00
[  695.820555] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  695.833363] scsi host4: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  695.925971] usb 2-2.1.3.4: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  695.973043] scsi host4: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success

Connected USB device overview as tree
lsusb -t

/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci-hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl8821au, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 10000M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 10000M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 10000M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 10000M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=, Driver=, 480M

USB overview as flat list
lsusb

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link Archer T2U PLUS [RTL8821AU]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 2109:0715 VIA Labs, Inc. VL817 SATA Adaptor
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 2109:0715 VIA Labs, Inc. VL817 SATA Adaptor
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 2109:0715 VIA Labs, Inc. VL817 SATA Adaptor
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 2109:0715 VIA Labs, Inc. VL817 SATA Adaptor
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 2109:0822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.1 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 2109:0715 VIA Labs, Inc. VL817 SATA Adaptor
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 2109:0822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.1 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.1 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:8822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB Billboard Device   
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:2822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2109:2822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

PCI
lspci

00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM2711 PCIe Bridge (rev 20)
01:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2142 USB 3.1 Host Controller

Raspberry Pi OS boot config
cat /boot/config.txt

# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# USB 3.1 host controller ASM2142
dtoverlay=pcie-32bit-dma

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]


Basically the only difference I have in my config text shown above compared to the default is the line dtoverlay=pcie-32bit-dma that is needed for the PCIe card that adds USB 3 and USB-C ports.
None of the harddrives show up in /dev. I would expect to see for example /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd and /dev/sde for the five connected drives.
Nor are any of the five drives shown in the list of block devices known to the system:
lsblk

NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0 29.1G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
`-mmcblk0p2  179:2    0 28.9G  0 part /
mmcblk0boot0 179:32   0    4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1 179:64   0    4M  1 disk 

Any idea what I can do to make them show up?
